# quantmod getSymbols google duplicate bug

Tags: r, quantmod

I keep getting an error when trying to extract data for google sources using `getSymbols()`.

Essentially, the dates of 2003 December 28-30 are "missing", and it then defaults the minimum date to 2001, as opposed to the minimum date that I am specifying.

Is there a way around this error so I may correctly and completely pull the data from google as the source for my `getSymbols` function?

Please see my code below:

```
install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)

ticks <- c("XLF", "XLK")

getSymbols(ticks, src = "google", 
       from = as.Date("1999-12-01"), to = as.Date("2017-05-11"))
```

Below is the warning message that I receive:

> Warning message:
>   In getSymbols.google(Symbols = c("XLF", "XLK"), env = ,  :
>     google duplicate bug - missing Dec 28,29,30 of 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't related to the warning about duplicates. Rather, it appears that Google Finance is limiting the number of observations you can download at a time to ~4000.

This happens if you go to their [historical prices page for XLF](https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=700196&startdate=May%2014%2C%201999&enddate=May%2013%2C%202017&num=30&ei=4hgXWcCLEaqGjAGI9764Aw&start=4500), select a date range larger than 4000 days, and click the [Download to spreadsheet link](http://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=700196&startdate=May%2014%2C%201999&enddate=May%2013%2C%202017&num=30&ei=4hgXWcCLEaqGjAGI9764Aw&start=4500&output=csv).

For now, you can work-around this by making multiple calls to `getSymbols` that are each for less than 4000 days of history, then combining the results.

Something like:

```
from <- "1999-12-01"
to <- "2017-05-11"
for (tick in ticks) {
  one <- getSymbols(tick, src = "google", from = from, to = "2010-12-31", auto.assign = FALSE)
  two <- getSymbols(tick, src = "google", from = "2011-01-01", to = to, auto.assign = FALSE)
  assign(tick, rbind(one, two))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the background and answer Joshua - it appears that the error still persists on those dates, but, with the function you created, the ticks now have a more complete time series. Separately, is it possible to download monthly data in this format? Or is it best to download the data and use a to.monthly() call?